# RDP client loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void RDP(string pass)
{
    try
    {
        rdp.Server = TBIP.Text;
        rdp.UserName = TBUserName.Text;
        IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
        secured.ClearTextPassword = pass;
        rdp.Connect();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

This standard request is working perfect:

```
RDP("123");
```

How I can make a loop. This for example does not work:

```
foreach (var p in pwd)
{
    RDP(p);
    Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
    rdp.Disconnect();
    rdp.AllowDrop = true;
}
```

It throws an error at line '59'.

```
rdp.Server = TBIP.Text;
```

"Exception Output"

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClient8.set_Server(String pServer)
   at AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient8.set_Server(String value)
   at RDP.Form1.RDP() in c:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RDP\RDP\Form1.cs:line 59
```

Comment: Care to share the error message or is it a guessing game? "Doesn't work" means you get an error, *right*? **What error**?

Answer (score 0):

I could repeat your error, but I cannot test with RDP extensively, but maybe [this post](http://www.codepartners.com/Blog/TabId/110/PostId/139/what-to-do-when-error-hresult-efail-returns-from-a-call-to-a-com-component.aspx) can help you.